# using a global variable in multiple files

Tags: c++, global-variables, linker-errors

I have a project using cocos2d-x library that contains a lot of classes. I have a .h file contains a global vector. I want to initialize it when the program starts in an intro page class. Intro page class has a graphical surface and a loader. Then I want to use that vector in my main class. The global vector's code is like bellow:

```
//globals.h
#ifndef _GLOBAL_H
#define _GLOBAL_H
#include <vector>

vector<int> a;
#endif
```

I am using push_back in intro page class. I have used **extern** and **static** keywords. my program makes a runtime linker error and it say your vector have been declared in appDelegate class (base class of cocos2d). when I put a static keyword behind it, it don't give me that linker error but it don't work correctly.
how can I correct this error? if you have another idea instead of this one, please share it. thank you.

Comment: [`extern` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm working in a code base now that has hundreds of randomly strewn globals all over the place. There are extern keywords everywhere and it's very ugly. Use a class to wrap your global as a static member variable or at the very least, isolate it to a header file as is suggested by Rob below. Global/extern pairs are not elegant IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a design like the following:

**shared.cpp**

```
vector<int> a;
```

**shared.h**

```
extern vector<int> a;
```

**somewhere.cpp**

```
#include "shared.h"
void code() {
  a.push_back(10);
}
```

Mind that, since you are using C++, you can uses classes as namespaces to avoid cluttering the global namespace, eg:

**shared.cpp**

```
vector<int> Common::a;
```

**shared.h**

```
class Common {
  public:
    static vector<int> a;
}
```

**somewhere.cpp**

```
#include "shared.h"
void code() {
  Common::a.push_back(10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have multiple declarations of an object, but you should only have one definition. To accomplish this, use `extern` to mark the declarations and the lack of `extern` to mark the definition.

In your header file, do this:

```
extern std::vector<int> a;
```

In exactly one of your source code files, do this:

```
std::vector<int> a;
```